# How to assign values to Attributes by passing argument using from method?

Tags: java, object, methods, static, arguments

> I need to assign YEAR, MONTH, DAY attributes to values just only using one set method. therefore I pass DATE.YEAR, DATE.MONTH, DATE.DATE as an argument also with values by calling set method line by line. You can make changes anything to the set method. But You cannot make changes to the main method.

```
   class Date{
    static int YEAR;
    static int MONTH;
    static int DAY;

    public void set(int field,int value){
        //i need to put code here to assign YEAR, MONTH, DAY to values
    }
    public void printDate(){
        System.out.println(YEAR+"-"+MONTH+"-"+DAY);
    }

}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Date d1=new Date();
        d1.set(Date.YEAR,2016); //set(int field, int value)
        d1.set(Date.MONTH,05);
        d1.set(Date.DAY,30);
        d1.printDate(); //2016-5-30
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark `YEAR`, `MONTH` AND `DAY` as final and use them in comparison in `set()` method

```
    class Date {

        static final int YEAR = 0;
        static final int MONTH = 1;
        static final int DAY = 2;

        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;

        public void set(int field, int value) {
            if (field == YEAR)
                this.year = value;
            else if (field == MONTH)
                this.month = value;
            else if (field == DAY)
                this.day = value;
        }

        public void printDate() {
            System.out.println(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain to me why you make YEAR, MONTH, DAY as final and also why you get a year, month, day again?

Comment: Because you don't change in `set()` method, So I just make them constants using `final` and shared to all objects using `static` and make variables related to every object

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use constructor instead of method,

within Date class

```
public Date(int YEAR, int MONTH, int DAY){
this.YEAR=YEAR;
this.MONTH = MONTH;
this.DAY = DAY;
}
```

and remove static from variable which you initialized, if you use satic you have to assign value for variable in same line.

your code would be

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
        Date d1=new Date(2016, 05, 30);
        d1.printDate(); //2016-5-30
    }
```

Comment: question is I cannot change the main method. because it's given me from an assignment.